# How do I extract with tar to a different directory?

Tags: tar

This doesn't work:

```
tar xf /tmp/foo.tar.gz foo/bar
tar: foo/bar: Not found in archive
```

It's not obvious to me what would do this beyond extracting it in place and moving the files over.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From `man tar`:

```
     -C directory
         In c and r mode, this changes the directory before adding the
         following files.  In x mode, change directories after opening the
         archive but before extracting entries from the archive.
```

i.e, `tar xC /foo/bar -f /tmp/foo.tar.gz` should do the job.
(on FreeBSD, [but GNU tar is basically the same in this respect, see "Changing the Working Directory" in its manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#SEC117))

Comment: I reccommend to test this behaviour with non-GNU versions of *tar*. Solaris manual page only mentions this option in combination of *add* and *replace* operations. Being curious I've tested it with an *extract* operation. Solaris' *tar* did **not** issue any error or warning and extracted the archive in the current folder =:-/

Comment: Also doesn't work on the AIX version of tar: 'File -C not present in the archive' - the '-C' does work for creating tarballs.

Comment: Is it possible to swap out the main directory with a new name?

Answer (score 10):

if you want to extract an tar archive elsewhere just *cd* to the destination directory and untar it there:

```
 mkdir -p foo/bar
 cd foo/bar
 tar xzvf /tmp/foo.tar.gz
```

The command you've used would search the file `foo/bar` in the archive and extract it.

Answer (score 8):

Doing:

```
(cd foo/bar ; tar xf /tmp/foo.tar.gz )
```

would do the job.

Basically, what is does is spawning a new shell (the parentheses), in this subshell, change directory to `foo/bar` and then untar the file.

You can change the `;` by a `&&` to be sure the `cd` works fine.

Comment: Wow that you can start a shell just like that is pretty cool! I had no idea you could do that.

Answer (score 5):

The command:

`tar -xzvf foo.tar.gz -C /home/user/bar/`

will extract the input file "foo.tar.gz", into the directory `/home/user/bar`, while printing the processed files.

Answer (score 1):

Change the directory where you want to extract

```
cd /u02/restore
```

if location of the extract file under /u01/backup.tar then

Extract as follows:

```
cd /u02/restore
tar -xvf /u01/backup.tar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -xf ancd.tar.gz my/name/file
```

you can give file name with `./file` after tar file.

```
tar -xf ancd.tar.gz ./my/name/file
```

if it is working means you have created a tar with `./`. use less command to see tar content.

```
less ...tar.file
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into what seems to be a similar issue and have resolved it.

The issue was in the file creation rather than the created file.

When attempting to tar up and transfer a file in dir A, I provided the path to the original file in the tar command

```
tar -cvf MyFile.tar /foo/bar/dir/not/needed/path/*
```

What I was able to do to resolve is

```
cd /foo/bar/dir/not/needed/
tar -cvf /tmp/MyFile.tar path*
```

On transferring and extracting the tarball, the required subdirs are created.

```
tar -xvf MyFile.tar
```