# Unable to extract entire tar to a particular directory in solaris

Tags: directory, solaris, tar

I wish to extract  `/tmp/moht/104.tar` to `/tmp/moht/` directory

```
ls -ltr /tmp/moht/104.tar
-rwxrwxr-x   1 meadmin  meadmin  933498880 Jan  5 07:03 /tmp/moht/104.tar
```

I tried the below commands, but it does not extract to `/tmp/moht/` directory.

It does not even print any output for extraction despite me using the `-v` option with `tar` command.

Below is everything I tried.

```
tar -xvf 104.tar --directory /tmp/moht/
tar -zvxf 104.tar --directory /tmp/moht/
tar -zvxf 104.tar -C /tmp/moht/
tar -jvxf 104.tar -C /tmp/moht/
```

If I `cd /tmp/moht` and fire this command `tar -xf 104.tar` then the files get extracted alright.

I'm using Sun Solaris Sparc.  I do not wish to cd but give absolute path for both the tar file as well as the destination. I am not using GNU tar, but the tar that comes with Solaris.

This will be a part of a script so all the filenames and paths will be changed to variables; hence my requirement is very specific.
Can you please suggest?

Comment: Linking in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23744/how-do-i-extract-with-tar-to-a-different-directory?rq=1 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187692/unable-to-extract-to-specific-directory?rq=1

Comment: @JeffSchaller `tar xC /tmp/moht -f /tmp/moht/104.tar
tar: C: unknown function modifier
`

Comment: @JeffSchaller the links you shared seem to indicate `cd` is the only option … Do you agree ?

Answer (score 3):

[Solaris tar](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E29030/tar-1.html) does not support the (presumably GNU tar) `-C` option during extraction to change directory before extraction. The Solaris tar `-C` option *specifies which files or directories are to be archived or extracted*. As a result, you need to `cd` to the directory where you want the extracted files to be put.

```
cd /tmp/moht && tar xf 104.tar
```

Note that Solaris tar does not use hyphenated functions like `-xf ...`, but rather bare letter options: `xf ...`. Also note that `104.tar` indicates an uncompressed tar file, so you do not need the `j` or `z` options; Solaris tar will automatically recognize compressed tar files for you.

Comment: Solaris `tar` has supported the `-` on the options since Solaris 8 or so at the latest, it's just documented in the Sun manner - a footnote buried somewhere that I can't find.  And my experience with (older?) Solaris `tar` in automatically recognizing compressed archives has been poor...

Comment: Thanks, Andrew! I didn't have an active Solaris system at-hand to prove or disprove the `-` support, so I based my claim on the documentation. At least they didn't say "SunOS"?!?

Comment: Solaris tar supports -C for creation only. The version from SchilliX added support for extraction as well.  See: https://sourceforge.net/p/schillix-on/schillix-on/ci/default/tree/usr/src/cmd/tar/ and BTW: Hyphens are tolerated for the first argument since the early 1980s and the -C option is from BSD-4.2 (1982).